# Select range to display dropdown box did not work

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to alter my vba code according to mr Jeeped so that it only display dropdown box at selected range from 7-10 and from 15 to the last row in excel. However, i did not work and I still can select dropdown box at row 11.

Here is the piece of code, however, I notice that with this edition from Mr Jeeped, the speed is very slow.

I also have the test file here, please have a  look:[download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9nm7Ppv6_P9VkZzdnNtRHB5cDA/view?usp=sharing)

My original code: It displayed dropdown box from row 7 till the last row.

```
Private priArray
Private priIsFocus As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 6 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    Dim e As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Not IsArray(priArray) Then
        e = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        priArray = sh.Range("C5:C" & e).Value2
    End If
    Call HienComboBox
Else
    Call AnComboBox
End If
End Sub
```

Here is the altered code according to Mr Jeeped suggestion:

```
Private priArray
Private priIsFocus As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 6 And Target.Column = 1 Then

    Dim e As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ReDim priArray(0)
    For e = 7 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case e
        Case 7 To 10, Is >= 15
            priArray(UBound(priArray)) = .Range("A" & e).Value2
            ReDim Preserve priArray(UBound(priArray) + 1)
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
Next e
ReDim Preserve priArray(UBound(priArray) - 1)
End With
    Call HienComboBox
Else
    Call AnComboBox
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, it's **Dr.** Jeeped.

Comment: Why does the code have to be in a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event macro? This runs every time another cell is selected, not when a relevant cell's value changes. What is important to make this code change the array values? Surely the combobox doesn't have to have its list changed **every** time that a user clicks a different cell...?

Comment: I really don't know, I just have some basic excel and vba knowledge. This is far beyond my knowledge. I just got this code from the internet and use it. Dr Jeeped could u help me to alter this code?